# Performance testing a batch job using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, outbound, s4hana

I am new to jmeter. I have a scenario where I need to run a batch job from jmeter. This batch job will trigger the invoices in SAP S/4HANA application and via API manager the invoice will reach the end system.

Let me know how to script for this scenario?

Thanks in advance,
Sony

This is for SAP S/4HANA application and the invoices are outbound.

Comment: It is SAP S/4 HANA

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you the scenario outline:

1. Trigger the batch somehow (if it is done via an API endpoint - go for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if you need to run a command or program - go for [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler), etc.)
2. Wait for the batch completion. Use a [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and under this controller query for the batch status in loop until the status becomes "finished" or "complete" or "done" or whatever. Come up with a While Controller's condition to run until the status becomes expected or timeout occurs, whatever comes the first
3. Put everything under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure end-to-end processing time